# Why Post Request in Jquery Ajax Table to MySql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I clicked the button the it will not work to post a data to mysqli. Why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#switch<?php echo $id ?>").click(function() {

    var status = $('#status<?php echo $id ?>').val();
    var id = $('#p_id<?php echo $id ?>').val();

    $.post("action.php", {
      status: status,
      id: id
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors and what are your expectations of the output for ` $("#switch<?php echo $id ?>").`?

Comment: Did you check your console and network tab(So that can check either request is fire from browser or not)?

Comment: I want to update status when the button is toggled to mySql. @NewToJS

Comment: That is a while loop inside a table...

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use + operator for concat the value.

$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#switch"+<?php echo $id; ?>).click(function() {
        var status = $('#status'+<?php echo $id; ?>).val();
        var id = $('#p_id'+<?php echo $id ?>).val();
        $.post("action.php", {
          status: status,
          id: id
        });
      });
    });
```